# How to make comparison with decimal places

Tags: mysql, perl

In mysql if I want to do a simple qu ery :

```
select * from testtable where id = 192.1111
```

and i just want to select upto 2 decimal places, how do i go about it ?

conclusion should be that the testtable should pick values like 192.1111 and also 192.1133
etc

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to select the numbers that match the first 2 decimals? the two examples you wrote are valid results?

Comment: ya precisely @MiguelPrz

Comment: So basically `(id - 192.11) < 0.01`?

Comment: Are you rounding to 192.11, or truncating to 192.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return all the results that match the first 2 decimal points, try using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable 
WHERE id like '192.11%'
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09817/1).

Good luck.

Comment: Works awesomely. Thanks a lot !!